# Show that a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, matrix-analysis

Let $U$ be a symmetric,positive definite matrix and let $Q \ne I$ be an orthogonal matrix s.t. $\det(Q)>0$. I want to show $$(Q-I)^tU(Q-I)$$ is positive definite

---

I want to show that $$\langle (Q-I)^tU(Q-I) v,v\rangle \geq 0$$ for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and equality holds iff $v=0$.

So I wrote $$\langle (Q-I)^tU(Q-I) v,v\rangle = \langle U(Q-I) v,(Q-I)^ v\rangle $$

Let's set $w = (Q-I) v$, then I have

$$\langle Uw,w \rangle \geq 0$$

for every $w \in \mathbb{R^n}$ since *$U$ is positive definite* and equality holds iff $$w=0$$

Now, $w=0$ iff $Qv = v$

but this does not imply that $v=0$... I don't know how to move now

Comment: This is not true. E.g. when $Q=1\oplus U$ for some $U\ne I$, then $Q-I$ and in turn $(Q-I)^tU(Q-I)$ are singular.

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $U=I$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Well, so I guess that all I can say is that it's positive semidefinite, right? @Exodd

Comment: for any $A$, $A^TUA$ is positive semidefinite @Vefhug

Comment: Thanks. Just one last thing: can we say something about its trace? I'd like to show that $\text{tr}(A^T U A) >0$, but I don't know how to do it @Exodd

Comment: I think I should use the hypothesis that $det(A)>0$ @Exodd

Comment: @Vefhug no need

Comment: Could you please show me how to prove it? @Exodd

Comment: @Vefhug You already did it : $<A^TUAv,v> = <UAv, Av> = <Uw,w>\ge 0$

Comment: I was referring to prove that the the trace of $A^T U A$ was strictly greater than 0 @Exodd

Comment: @Vefhug Since it is positive semidefinite, then the trace is always $\ge 0$. It is zero if and only if the matrix itself is zero, but you can prove that $A^TUA$ is zero iff $A=0$

Comment: thanks that's almost clear. Just one last thing: I'm trying to show $A^T U A =0$ iff $A=0$, but I am not able to show the $=>$ implication. How should I move?

Comment: @Vefhug if $A$ is not zero then there is a $v$ such that $w = Av$ is not zero, so $v^TA^TUAv = w^TUw>0$, so $A^TUA$ is not zero

Comment: The idea is clear, but you showed that $v^tT A^T UA v >0$, but this is just a scalar. How does  this imply that the whole matrix $A^T U A$ is non zero? After this point the whole picture is clear to me @Exodd

Comment: If $A^TUA=0$ then necessarily $v^TA^TUAv=0$ @Vefhug